# Start Windows Terminal from the CLI and pass in an executable command to run

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-terminal

I can start [Windows Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) with `wt`. I have read the [Windows Terminal documentation on command-line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows), and it just covers passing an argument for setting up terminal panes, not passing in actual executable commands.

For example, a minimal reproducible example: Requires Windows Terminal installed:

Open a [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) prompt in Windows and type:

```
dir | wt
```

This starts Windows Terminal, but it does not receive the `dir` command. How does one pass the executable command to Windows Terminal?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use

```
wt new-tab -p "Command Prompt" -d "%cd%" cmd /k dir
```

- You can omit `new-tab` (it’s a default command).
- Omitting `-d "%cd%"` seems to be equivalent to `-d "%USERPROFILE%"`.
- You can omit `-p "Command Prompt"` if your default profile is set to the cmd.exe profile. Check the `wt` settings in the following file (Windows):

  ```
  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json
  ```

Try a more complex command than `dir`, for instance

```
wt new-tab -p "Command Prompt" -d "%cd%" cmd /k "dir & type "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json""
```

Please check the *[How to pass commands into the shell opened in new Windows Terminal](https://superuser.com/q/1564090/376602)* question as well.

Comment: Thank you that is brillant! I don't know how you figured it out. I read the the windows doc and wt --help, and googled, and didnt get a clue at all.

Comment: Add thanks to your link, for anyone looking for the power shell equivalent: `Start-Process wt.exe -ArgumentList "PowerShell.exe", "-NoExit", "-Command", "dir"`

Comment: The `new-tab` param seems to open a new window for me.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! You can totally automate your routines with this one!